# Auto suggestion for imageview and textView in android studio .xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Auto  suggestion for  imageview and textView  in android studio .xml  files doesn't work.

I've tried all solutions mentioned in other SO threads like **invalidating cache**, **deleting/rebuilding  folders** in *AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.2*, **deleting .gradle files**,**power save mode**  and clean-rebuilding the project, I've even **moved** all **source codes and resources** to a new project but the problem still exists.
The new project imageview and textview elements work fine before transferring files from the main project!!
I'm using androidX in the case it helps!

[xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgSFb.png)
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys3Hk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issues has been solved by

- cleaning the project (AS menu -> Build-> Clean Project)-->
- closing AS -->
- **deleting the following directory**
  *%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.2*
- reopening AS and building the project